# How to select all the columns without the timestamp and date types?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm comparing two tables which have a lot of columns. I'm interested in all the columns except the timestamps and dates.

I'm doing this:

```
select row1, row2, row3, row4, ..., row39, row40
from mytable1
minus
select row1, row2, row3, row4, ..., row39, row40
from mytable2;
```

I select all the columns one by one, except the three which are dates and timestamp.

How I can simplify all this to not have to put all the colunms one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really "simplify" it.  You can get all the columns easily by using a query, such as:

```
select column_name
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'mytable1' 
      data_type not in ('date' . . .)
```

With the column names, you can manually construct the query without having to type all of them in.

Comment: Thanks, now I'll finish a little faster. ;)